# Rutas de acceso de codigo devuelven valor

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

> CS0161:'TusuariosController.NombredeUsuario(int)': no todas las rutas
> de acceso de código devuelven un valor.

Código:

```
private string NombredeUsuario(int id)
    {
        using (BB_SQLContext db = new BB_SQLContext())
        {
            try
            {
                string resultado = "";

                if (id != 0)
                {
                    //Usar Linq para mostrar datos.Construir la consulta
                    var data = from a in db.Tusuario
                               join b in db.Tcontraseña on a.Id equals b.Id
                               where a.Id == id
                               select new Tusuario()
                               {
                                   User = a.User,
                                   TipoPermiso = a.TipoPermiso,
                               };

                    resultado = data.ToList().ToString();

                    return resultado;
                }                                       
                   return resultado;                  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError(" ", "Error al obtener el nombre del usuario -" + ex.Message);                   
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hola, Arancha. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir el código en lugar de la imagen? De esta forma la persona que pueda ayudarte con tu duda tendrá mayor facilidad de copiar el código y reproducir el error.

Comment: Prueba añadiendo `return null` en el `catch` despues de `AddModelError`

Comment: Gracias !! Funcionó

Comment: Claro. El error es claro "no todas las rutas devuelven valor". En esos casos, debes seguir todas las posibles opciones que pueden pasar en el método, y todas deben devolver algo. Y en tu caso, si se producía una excepción, no estabas devolviendo nada. Es normal a veces no considerar el catch, pero hay que hacerlo tambien :)

Answer (score 0):

según veo tu código la solución más simple y eficiente que veo y que soluciona el problema es la sigueinte:

```
private string NombredeUsuario(int id)
{
    string resultado = ""; // Declaramos aquí mejor
    using (BB_SQLContext db = new BB_SQLContext())
    {
        try
        {
            // Mejor declarar en el cuerpo de la función
            // string resultado = "";
            if (id != 0)
            {
                //Usar Linq para mostrar datos.Construir la consulta
                var data = from a in db.Tusuario
                           join b in db.Tcontraseña on a.Id equals b.Id
                           where a.Id == id
                           select new Tusuario()
                           {
                               User = a.User,
                               TipoPermiso = a.TipoPermiso,
                           };
                 
                resultado = data.ToList().ToString();

                // Redundante, se puede omitir
                //return resultado;
            }                                
            // Redundante, se puede omitir
            // return resultado;                  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(" ", "Error al obtener el nombre del usuario -" + ex.Message);               
        }
    }

    // Retornamos el resultado, o resultado = "" si hubo o mensaje de error.
    // aunque podríamos variarlo a NULL en la declaración de la variable
    // si lo preferimos
    return resultado;
}
```